# Conditional templates in Java?

Tags: c#, java

In C# I can do this:

```
public class QuadTree<T> where T : IHasRect
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `where T : IHasRect` means that `T` is a type that must implement the `IHasRect` interface, the Java equivalent is

```
public class QuadTree<T extends HasRect>
```

Read the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for more information.

Comment: +1 "If where T : IHasRect means that T is a type that must implement the IHasRect interface" yes, this is precisely what it means in C#, feel free to remove the `if` :)

Comment: I'll let it there, at least to inform future readers that are neither comfortable with C# generics (like me, admittedly), nor comfortable with Java generics. Thanks for confirming.